# how to print time took for each package in requirement.txt to be installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, requirements.txt

Is there any convenient way to print the time took for each package when running `pip install -r requirements.txt`?

I would like something like `pip install -r requirement.txt --print-times`
and instead of just printing the names of the package and the versions I would like the output to look something like this:

```
Collecting shellescape==3.8.1
  Using cached shellescape-3.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.1 kB)
  took 2.4 seconds
Collecting lxml==4.5.2
  Using cached lxml-4.5.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (5.4 MB)
    Collecting gevent==20.9.0
  Using cached gevent-20.9.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (6.1 
  took 4.4 seconds
```

etc...

I did not find this data under --verbose.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I'm aware of options like writing a bash/python scripts but I'm looking for a simple flag or single-line command.

Comment: There is no flag or command to do that. You would have to hack into _pip_'s code.

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestions for you, you can use a python programm:

- Open you requirement.txt (`f = open('requirement.txt', 'r')`)
- Read the file (`doc = f.readlines()`)
- In a for loop take each lines
- Initialise a timer (`t0 = time.time()`)
- Run pip install with pip package in python
- Display the time it tooks (`time.time() - t0`)
- Use an alias to replace run this script insteed of pip install

Comment: where is this information printed? where can I grep it from?
I'm aware of the second option but I'm looking for a simple and convenient way (some kind of a oneliner)

Comment: I am not enough familiar with grep but here is some doc: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/grep-command-linux-unix-examples

You may have issues when there is dependancies. It is the reason why python script is better.

Comment: @TomerCohen a third solution

Comment: Where in the pip install output do you see the times? how can you grep them if they aren't there?

Comment: You can have it using the python package pip into python script.
To use it with grep, run a micro python script that run pip using this package and display time by a print... It is the only solution I have.

I thinked it exists an option to get the time

Comment: @TomerCohen updated answer with pip package in python. I see only one solution for you...

Answer (score 1):

create a bash script with this content

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    start=`date +%s`
    pip install $line
    end=`date +%s`
    runtime=$((end-start))
    echo "took $runtime seconds"
done < requirements.txt
```

Comment: requirements.txt does not contain only packages, it can contain lines like --extra-index-url and --trusted-host